# Need to populate a custom field in User while we create a User in SF via Azure AD - Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, azure

Scenario : Implemented Single Sign On - Azure AD with User provisioning option.

If a user is created we can set Standard fields on User creation, But how are Public Groups and Permission sets being handled.

Work Around : I am trying to create a custom field in User table, which I intend/trying to populate from Azure while creating a user. Is this possible from Azure?

Or Please suggest another workaround Or is this feature available in SFDC that while creating a user via Azure AD(SSO) Public Groups & Permission Sets be assigned.

Please Advise.